# Rails 3 On Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to linux and newer to rails. I installed ruby 1.8.7 which is compatible with rails 3, i did the gem update and it installed for me rails 3.0.1 and all necessary files. However when i make a new rails application using the 'rails new myapp' command i notice that the script folder only has one file 'script/rails' can some one help me out i have no idea hat i dad wrong and where to go from here

Comment: First of all try the following "gem -v" , "sqlite3 --version". Does that give you proper output. These are necessary to start with,if uare using sqlite3 by default.

Answer (score 2):

What are you expecting?  The ../script/ folder by default only has the "rails" file.

Comment: OK, the book didn't indicate that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look inti this link:- It has complete steps to install Rails in ubuntu.
http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/getting-started/installation/linux.
Installing sqlite3 may be missing in the link , hence you can use the below commands:-

sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev ruby-dev followed by

"sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby"

Answer (score 0):

script/rails is a new feature in rails 3.  script/server, script/console and all script/* variants now have a: script/rails server (or simply: rails server) equivalents